# .netcore 3.1 web app taking randomly a lot of time to response

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a .netCore 3.1 on azure web app who interract with a CosmosDb database and some others services. Generally speaking the request time is correct :

[image]

But sometimes I have request who takes a lot of time to answer at any step of the process :

[image]

I can't figure it out and I don't know where I can begin to take a look. Looking at the webApp configuration, the "AlwaysOn" is on and there is a Get request on my API every 5 minutes.

Can it be something related to the servicePlan or ASE ? Or maybe the DI of my API ?

Comment: you should instrument your application with Application Insights in order to figure out the reason for this long requests. It can be DNS resolution, some network issues, bad memory usage, multiple reasons...

Comment: I have already set the Application Insights in my app and added `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();`. Am I missing something ?